# What do these yellow key frames mean and why can't I select or delete them?

Tags: keyframes

[image]

I'm new to animating in Blender. Using version 2.82 and these key frames (not the bars between the keyframes) look exactly like the white ones when the white ones are selected, but I can't seem to do anything to them and they don't appear under summary.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked from which channel they are? Open up the dropdown under e.g. 'hand.l' on the left.

Comment: They don't appear at all under hand.l. Do I assume that those key frames are a visual bug? https://i.imgur.com/veXP8iR.png

Comment: Switch to the dopesheet view (not the action editor). Try looking in the graph editor. Any luck with that?

Comment: maybe share your file? (delete all the useless objects): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @ Ray Mairlot, no, he says he can't select or delete the keyframes

Comment: @Leander They also appear in the dope sheet, not sure how to read the graph editor though, but I've uploaded the file.

Comment: Delete the "I" from your search bar.

Comment: yes you were unable to see the keyframes for scale

Comment: @Ere Please don't add 'solved' in the title. If the answer has solved your problem you can mark it as accepted by ticking the checkmark on the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the filter/search option of the dopesheet. You have entered the filter string `i` and hence only the names of curves containing *i* are showing. (Even though we still get the visual indication that there are more keys, which we can't select.)

Simply remove the search term, to view all of the keys of the selected objects.

[image: remove search]